# WARN: Parameter didn't match accepted pattern in Struts 2

Tags: regex, parameters, configuration, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I'm using Struts2.3.28. When I submit a form which uses the [`submit` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/submit-tag.html) with the `method` attribute, I'm getting this warning:

```
WARN  com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor 
     warn- Parameter [method:save] didn't match accepted 
     pattern [[\w+((\.\w+)|(\[\d+\])|(\(\d+\))|
     (\['(\w|[\u4e00-\u9fa5])+'\])|(\('(\w|[\u4e00-\u9fa5])+'\)))*]]!
```

I have `struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation` set to `true`.

I think this `acceptParamNames` property for the [Parameters Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) (sort of a whitelist, it seems) was added in some recent version... The docs only says (basically)

> "don't touch this"
> .

Great! So, what am I supposed to do if I still want to use the `method` attribute of `submit` tag?

**Further:** it's not clear for me the implications of this warning. If the pattern does not match neither the whitelist `acceptParamNames` nor the blacklist `excludeParams` (ah, the consistency), what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Are you sure that you use 2.3.28? Have you modified accepted or excluded patterns? Cannot reproduce your issue in my project.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set devmode ? https://struts.apache.org/docs/devmode.html

Comment: [Default exclude pattern](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/support-2-3/xwork-core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/security/DefaultExcludedPatternsChecker.java#L21) excludes `method:` and `isExcluded` [comes before](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/support-2-3/xwork-core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ParametersInterceptor.java#L386) `isAccepted`. Have you modified exclude pattern?

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes, I've removed that restriction.

Comment: That answers why you are seeing exact this message. But DMI should still work, right? If not then it is hard to tell why w/o additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a developer notification that is invoked from the method

```java
 protected boolean isAccepted(String paramName) {
        AcceptedPatternsChecker.IsAccepted result = acceptedPatterns.isAccepted(paramName);
        if (result.isAccepted()) {
            return true;
        }
        notifyDeveloper("Parameter [#0] didn't match accepted pattern [#1]!", paramName, result.getAcceptedPattern());
        return false;
    }
```

it means that if the parameter name matches *the list of accepted patterns*, then it's passed by this interceptor (after checks for name length, and if it's not excluded).

New interceptor also checks the acceptance of the parameter value.

The whitelist and blacklist of parameters are managed by the `ParameterNameAware` action separately.

**Note:**

> Using `ParameterNameAware` could be dangerous as
> `ParameterNameAware#acceptableParameterName(String)` takes precedence
> over `ParametersInterceptor` which means if `ParametersInterceptor`
> excluded given parameter name you can accept it with
> `ParameterNameAware#acceptableParameterName(String)`.

---

The default list of patterns are settled during initialization (it's hardcoded using default constant value), so if you didn't use a parameter `acceptParamNames` in the interceptor configuration, Struts will use its default pattern list. But you can override the parameter value by specifying this parameter to the parameters interceptor.

**Note:** The method `notifyDeveloper` should only print in `devMode`, otherwise it prints only in `DEBUG` mode of the logger. You can also trace massages by changing a logger level to `TRACE`.

---

To use a `method` attribute of the submit tag you should:

1. Enable [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation):

```xml
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
```

<del>2. Override the list of *excluded* patterns.
the default list of exluded patterns contains a pattern that excludes `method:` parameter (and `action:` too). That is also mentioned by AleksandrM in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236044/struts2-warning-parameter-didnt-match-accepted-pattern/36289097#comment60164660_36236044).</del>

For more information see documentation for [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html).

Comment: To use DMI there is no need to override excluded pattern. DMI happens before parameters mapping.

Comment: Updated for better understanding.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding. DMI should work even if default pattern is used. The exclude pattern is for parameters not for DMI.

Comment: DMI it does but the submit tag generates URLs for default action mapper, which is using this parameter only if DMI is enabled.

Comment: Correct, so I will remove part 2.

Comment: I'm still not sure if we need to override the default accept  pattern. The crucial point, I think, is not to confuse http parameters with struts params. If I'm using DMI, a (http) parameter like "method:save" is received. Now, it's (perhaps) ok that this is rejected by the struts parameter interceptor, because we don't want this to be treated like a "common" parameter (calling the setter in the action), but only to be processed by the struts url-to-action+method mapping intelligence (which happens before the parameters mapping). It this is true (I'm not sure), then point 2 shouldn't be needed.

Comment: yes, the default action mapper handles this parameters by setting action mapping properties before the params or any other interceptor is invoked, but parameters still remains in the request and should be rejected from this interceptor, while rejected it shows a warning but you can suppress it. You don't need to override it.